# Openweathermap: json (min and max temp)

Tags: php, json, weather-api, openweathermap

I want to implement a weather module for my website. For this I chose "Openweathermap".

I want to get the min and max temperature for today and tomorrow.

**PHP**

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=london&mode=json");
$jsonData = json_decode($json_string, true);
$min_1 = $jsonData['list'][0]['temp'][0]['min'];
$max_1 = $jsonData['list'][0]['temp'][0]['max'];
$min_2 = $jsonData['list'][1]['temp'][0]['min'];
$max_2 = $jsonData['list'][1]['temp'][0]['max'];
echo $min_1.' - '.$max_1.'<br><br>';
echo $min_2.' - '.$max_2.'<br><br>';
```

But with this code I get no output (except the two "-").

**json file**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're placing an extra `[0]`:

```
//                                   V removed [0], temp doesn't have another array in an array
$min_1 = $jsonData['list'][0]['temp']['min'];
$max_1 = $jsonData['list'][0]['temp']['max'];
$min_2 = $jsonData['list'][1]['temp']['min'];
$max_2 = $jsonData['list'][1]['temp']['max'];
echo $min_1.' - '.$max_1.'<br><br>';
echo $min_2.' - '.$max_2.'<br><br>';
```

To get Celsius, attach `&units=metric`:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=london&mode=json&units=metric
```

Comment: Are the values I get there in °F? How can I convert this values to °C?

Comment: @KlippOhei Check my revised answer, it's much easier to get the API to do it. (Of course you could convert it yourself with `(F - 32) * 5/9`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra [0] that breaks your code (line 3 to 6)

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=london&mode=json");
$jsonData = json_decode($json_string, true);
$min_1 = $jsonData['list'][0]['temp']['min'];
$max_1 = $jsonData['list'][0]['temp']['max'];
$min_2 = $jsonData['list'][1]['temp']['min'];
$max_2 = $jsonData['list'][1]['temp']['max'];
echo $min_1.' - '.$max_1.'<br><br>';
echo $min_2.' - '.$max_2.'<br><br>';
```